# Incorporate data frame into LaTeX

Tags: tables

How can we incorporate data frame into LaTeX table as example below, with the values coming from the data frame ?

```
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{setspace}
```

and the code for the table:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Country List} \\
 \hline
 Country & ISO ALPHA&ISO ALPHA&ISO numeric\\
 \hline
 Afghan& AF    &AFG&   004\\
 Aland &   AX  & ALA   &248\\
 Albania &AL & ALB&  008\\
 Algeria    &DZ & DZA&  012\\
 American Samoa&   AS  & ASM&016\\
 Andorra& AD  & AND   &020\\
 Angola& AO  & AGO&024\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you looking for `pgfplotstable`? BTW, please provide a complete code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: every time I add a completed code such as \documentclass and \end{document}. I get error message.  **! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.**

Comment: This means you need to add `\begin{document}` after all `\usepackage` commands and before `\begin{tabular}...` (in this case).

Comment: you might be missing title = "test". Try putting it before the header line "output = ..."

Comment: @Ross, I don't think that makes a difference or resolve the issue of adding data frame to LaTex.

Comment: What data frame are you referring to? If you just want to set the table using this `.Rmd` setup you just need to add `title = "test"` to your header and `knit` the file in `RStudio`. Do not add `\begin{document}` and `end{document}`. `knitr` will look after that.

Comment: @marmot This is about R-markdown, not pure LaTeX.

Comment: Perhaps [How can I use a table generated by R in LaTeX?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25575) or [How can I use a table generated by Latex in R(xtable)?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/137334) will help.

Comment: @AlanMunn,  I rather use data frame than table because data frame are more flexible in terms of what you want to do with it.

Comment: Did you look at the linked answers? The `Hmisc` R package can deal with dataframes. But you would help out by actually giving some sample data to play with in R rather than just a LaTeX document.